# image size on container

Tags: html, css

I want to have an image that adjusts to container size.

Example: the container is 100x100 pixels and the image is 90x80 pixels, the smaller property of the image (height in this case) adjust to container size, and the bigger property overflow the container size.

How can I do this?

My code:

HTML

```
<div class="a-avatar">
  <img src="#" alt="profile picture">
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .a-avatar {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }

  .a-avatar img {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
```

Comment: Your code already seems to be doing that. Do you mean that you want one of the sides to **not** overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use background image, example:-

```
 div.avatar {
     background-image: url("paper.gif");

    height: 500px; /* You must set a specified height */
      background-position: center; /* Center the image */
      background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
      background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container 
    }
```